# How to upgrade PostGIS 2.0 to 2.1 on Windows 7?

Tags: postgis, update

PostGIS 2.1 was [recently released](http://postgis.net/2013/08/17/postgis-2-1-0) and I would really like to upgrade from 2.0, but can't quite figure it out.  I had previously installed PostgreSQL 9.2 and PostGIS 2.0 using StackBuilder.  Running `SELECT PostGIS_full_version();`, shows I currently have the following install base:

> "POSTGIS="2.0.3 r11132" GEOS="3.3.8-CAPI-1.7.8" PROJ="Rel. 4.8.0, 6
>   March 2012" GDAL="GDAL 1.9.2, released 2012/10/08" LIBXML="2.7.8"
>   LIBJSON="UNKNOWN" TOPOLOGY RASTER"

So I downloaded the tar.gz file, and after uncompressing it, **where do I copy the new 2.1 folders/files so that I can do a "soft upgrade"** using the `ALTER EXTENSION postgis UPDATE TO "2.1.0";` method?

Or am I missing additional intermediate steps, too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you downloaded the correct file? This might be what you are looking for:

http://winnie.postgis.net/download/windows/pg92/buildbot/postgis-pg92-binaries-2.1.0w32.zip

Or the 64-bit version, of course.

From the README.txt

-- Upgrading extension --
To upgrade an extension, it's just as easy. If you are using PgAdmin,
go to the extensions section and the postgis / postgis_topology.
Select the version drop down and bump what you have currently to the latest.

Comment: Or, in SQL:
ALTER EXTENSION postgis UPDATE TO "2.1.0"

Comment: Thank you!  I figured I had the wrong download, but couldn't find the right binaries to download for Windows.  Copied the files over from that location and upgraded very easily with `ALTER EXTENSION postgis UPDATE TO "2.1.0";`.