# postgis - get nth point of a polygon

Tags: postgis, polygon, point

I would like to create a postgresql function to correct geographic coordinates inside a polygon that are outside the -180 to 180 range of longitudes.

To do this, I thought I would create a function to loop through all the points in a polygon and do the correction.

However, I don't see a method for extracting the nth point in a polygon, only a linestring with ST_PointN.

Is this possible and/or am I going about this the correct way.

Comment: Doesn't PostGIS automatically correctly handle the +/- 180 meridian problem?

Comment: When I try to convert to a geography I get an out of range error (see my comment below). I wonder if it is because of my PostGIS version? I have: "POSTGIS="2.0.3 r11132" GEOS="3.3.8-CAPI-1.7.8" PROJ="Rel. 4.8.0, 6 March 2012" GDAL="GDAL 1.9.2, released 2012/10/08" LIBXML="2.7.8" LIBJSON="UNKNOWN" RASTER"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For PostGIS 2.1, you can just convert the geometry to a [geography type](http://postgis.net/docs/using_postgis_dbmanagement.html#PostGIS_Geography), where longitudes are always normalised to the -180/+180 range. For example, take these coordinates that are outside the range, and compare the normalised output:

```
SELECT ST_AsText(geom::geography::geometry)
FROM (SELECT 
  'POLYGON((180.12 -16.69,180.00 -16.80,179.89 -16.95,
            179.92 -17.02,180.18 -16.79,180.12 -16.69))'::geometry AS geom
) AS f;

POLYGON((-179.88 -16.69,180 -16.8,179.89 -16.95,179.92 -17.02,-179.82 -16.79,-179.88 -16.69))
```

Comment: This is my issue that started this question. When I run your example, I get--> ERROR: Coordinate values are out of range [-180 -90, 180 90] for GEOGRAPHY type
SQL state: 22023. What version of PostGIS are your using? I have: "POSTGIS="2.0.3 r11132" GEOS="3.3.8-CAPI-1.7.8" PROJ="Rel. 4.8.0, 6 March 2012" GDAL="GDAL 1.9.2, released 2012/10/08" LIBXML="2.7.8" LIBJSON="UNKNOWN" RASTER"

Comment: This is a feature for PostGIS 2.1. For older versions a more complicated method needs to be done...

Comment: Here is a post on upgrading to PostGIS 2.1 which doesn't seem to bad: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/69496/how-to-upgrade-postgis-2-0-to-2-1-on-windows-7

Comment: I would like to report that I was able to upgrade to PostGIS 2.1 and converting to the geography type normalized my coordinates.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [ST_DumpPoints](http://www.postgis.org/documentation/manual-2.0/ST_DumpPoints.html) and iterate over its results. It should be exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: I looked into this and am struggling with writing a function, but this seems like a legitimate way to go about it.

Comment: Yeah, upon furter inspection it doesn't look that easy, since some of the candidate functions only work on linestrings. At worst you could dump to WKT, edit and reconvert, but that's so ugly I almost abstained from typing it.

Comment: I still think the ST_DumpPoints function would work but I am having trouble with Postgres arrays. If I figure it out I will post the function I created.

Comment: How did you plan to move the vertices?

Comment: Unfortunately I haven't gotten there yet, fortunately I was able to upgrade to PostGIS 2.1 without incident and that took care of my issue as stated in the answer above.